# Force https through htaccess for logged in users

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, https, yii

I am trying to force https for all logged in users.  Most of my app requires a user to be logged in but I still have many pages that should only be http and others that should be served both through http (guests) and https (logged in users) depending on login status.

I am using the Yii framework and looking to force https for all pages for a logged in user.  Users are controlled through a module.

Here is my current .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#RedirectMatch 301 ^/tk/(.*)$ http://admin.mysite.com/$1
#RewriteRule ([a-z0-9-]+)/? http://$1.mysite.com [R=301,NC,L]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php

#RewriteRule . index.php
RewriteRule .* index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: considering you have the certificate set up already, is there any reason not to use https for all users all the time?

Comment: yes I have the certificate set up already, is there any down fall to using https all the time for all users?

Comment: There is a performance hit, but unless your site is very busy you won't notice it.

Comment: Well in regards to not falling into the trap of premature optimization I guess this could be a fitting solution for now and then just handle accordingly in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you use sessions or cookies, you will need to check the sessions, and if they are valid, then redirect the user to https site.

This needs to be done in PHP. No way to do this in pure .htaccess.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Yes I am using sessions and that is part of the reason I want logged in users to stay on https.  I am not sure how to implement what you are referring to with checking the session then redirecting to https. Unless you just mean doing something like this? `Yii::app()->user->isGuest` My concern came about after reading this [Forcing HTTPS in Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/25407-forcing-https-in-yii/page__view__findpost__p__124744)

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite rules are not the proper solution : it takes too much resources.

Better use :

```
RedirectPermanent / https://domain.tld
```

and if possible, not in a `.htaccess` file but in the apache configuration directly.

Comment: Looking over and doing some testing I am liking this approach the most so far.  I will accept an answer after more testing.  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a cookie named `session` for your sessions, you can use a RewriteCond to test for your session cookie

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} session
RewriteRule .* https://www.mysite.com/$0 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with filters.

[Yii CFilter documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFilter)

Sample of filter class:

```
class CHttpsCheckFilter extends CFilter {

protected function preFilter($filterChain) {
    //place your checking logic here.
    //$filterChain->controller is yor targer controller
    //other useful methods and fields you can find in official documentation.
    if ( !Yii::app()->getRequest()->isSecureConnection ) {            
        $url = 'https://your-new-path';
        Yii::app()->request->redirect($url);
        return false;
    } else
        return true;
}

protected function postFilter($filterChain) {
    return true;   
}
```

then, you need attach this filter to your controller, by implementing `filters` method in it:

```
public function filters()
{
    return array(
        'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
        array(
            'CHttpsCheckFilter',
        ),
    );
}
```

This is the basic functionality. You can add additional logic to filter, which can check target controller for your custom method for additional rules... or it may contain all security rules in it.